# How can i get access to the same instance of the class without creating one more bean id

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

I am new to Spring and the project which i am in currently is using Spring IOC .
This is the current Setup of my Application , which i tried to represent as Standalone 
This below class is started as a Process during server startup

Client.java

```
public final class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
            String[] beans = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            for (String string : beans) {
                System.out.println(beans);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

context.xml





      <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.tradeking" /> -->
       <context:annotation-config />



    <bean id="stream-core" class="com.StreamHandler" scope="singleton" init-method="init">
          <constructor-arg>
             <ref bean="streamingthread"/>
          </constructor-arg>
           </bean>

          <bean id="streamingthread" class="com.StreamingThread" scope="singleton" >
           </bean>

         </beans>
```

StreamHandler.java

```
package com;
    public class StreamHandler {
    private StreamingThread streamThread;
    public StreamHandler(StreamingThread streamThread) {
        this.streamThread = streamThread;
    }
    public void init() {
        this.streamThread.start();
    }
}
```

StreamingThread.java

```
   package com;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    public class StreamingThread extends Thread {
        private Set<String> streamSet = new HashSet();
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                    streamSet.add("Test" + 1);
                    System.out.println("Run Called");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now my question is that , i have got another class by name UbscHandler in which i need access to the streamSet which is present inside StreamingThread class

So i tried this way

added one more bean id inside the context.xml file  as shown

```
<context:annotation-config />
     <bean id="streamingthreadnew" class="com.StreamingThread" scope="singleton" > 


        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("streamingthreadnew")
        private StreamingThread sThread;
```

I am facing 2 issues here

1. i am not able to access the streamSet as it is private .

2.Instead of creating one more bean id  can i get access to that particular class using Spring style .

**Edited Part**

Right now i am getting

```
 Hi Streamed Thread Called0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Client.anotherMethod(Client.java:33)
    at com.Client.main(Client.java:26)
```

this is my context.xml

```
  <bean id="streamingthread" class="com.StreamingThread" scope="singleton" >
   </bean>

 </beans>



    **This is StreamingThread**     




   package com;

    import java.util.Set;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
    public  class Client{
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("streamingthread")
        private StreamingThread streamingthread;
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
                String[] beans = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
                for (String string : beans) {
                }
                Client c = new Client();
                c.anotherMethod();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void anotherMethod()
        {
            Set set = streamingthread.getData();
            System.out.println(set.size());
        }
    }
```

**This is my StreaminThread class**

```
   package com;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    public class StreamingThread extends Thread {
        int i=0;
        StreamingThread()
        {
            System.out.println("Hi Streamed Thread Called"+i);
        }

        private  Set<String> streamSet = new HashSet();


        public Set getData()
        {
            return streamSet;
        }

        public void run() {
            /*while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                    streamSet.add("Test" + 1);
                //s System.out.println("Run Called"+i);
                }
            }*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same object to be injected, then you must not define another bean, but use the same definition:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="stream-core" class="com.StreamHandler" scope="singleton" init-method="init">
        <constructor-arg><ref bean="streamingthread"/></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="streamingthread" class="com.StreamingThread" scope="singleton" />
</beans>
```

And if you want a field to be accessible, then add a method to your class that lets you access the field.

EDIT:

You can only inject (autowire) Spring beans into other Spring beans, obtained from the application context. Client is not a Spring bean, and you get an instance of it using `new Client()`. Spring is totally unaware of this class and of its instanciation, so it can't inject any object into this Client instance.

You must get the StreamingThread from the application context:

```
StreamingThread streamingThread = applicationContext.getBean(StreamingThread.class);
```

Comment: hi , thanks for the response , and you mean that i need to add a method inside the StreamingThread class that returns me the Set know ??

Comment: private fields are not accessible from the outside. That is basic OO stuff. If you want to make it accessible, you add a public method which gives access to the field (or its data), yes.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping . i am new to spring so i am not sure and thats why asked and thanks once again .

Comment: I was trying the way that was suggested but i was getting NPE , could you please help me  , i have edited my question in the edited part section

Comment: ya that solved the problem , thanks master for helping dummies like me .